# Angular 1.x and es6 multiple constants in a singular module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

So i've got the duty of converting a es5 to an es6 module.

How does one export/import an angular constant module if there are more than one constant in an angular module for ES6?

E.g.
**constants.js**

```
export default angular.module('myConstants', [])
  .constant('foo', {result: 'bar'})
  .constant('blah', {result: 'bar'});
```

**service.js**

```
import foo from './constants';
import blah from './constants'; // Tried this. This won't work
```

Does this mean i have to split my constants into separate modules? Or should i just convert them into ES6 constants using the const keyword?

P.p.s using webpack and the babel loader

P.s. I have to use psuedo-code as i cannot paste work code in.

Comment: That export statement is a syntax error. Did you mean to use `export default`?

Comment: Why would you use angular modules when you have ES6 modules?

Comment: @Bergi yes thank you. I've updated it.

Comment: @Bergi what do you mean?

Comment: Why wouldn't you have a simple `myConstants.js` file with `export const foo = 'bar'; export const blah = 'bar';`?

Comment: @Bergi that's what i'm not sure about. It's more about best practices. Is that logical equivalent and the best way to go about with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular `constant` service is just a type of service which is available during config phase and is the suggested way to store module constants (hence the name). It isn't a real constant and can be overwritten any time with `$provide.constant`.

Chained `angular.module(...)` exports [`Module` object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module) and doesn't make sense in non-Angular context.

Keep separate exports for Angular modules and ES6 modules. It is conventional to export Angular module [`name` property](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#name), a string that can be imported and used in other modules semantically.

```
export const foo = ...;

export default angular.module('myConstants', []).constant('foo', foo).name;
```

---

```
import myConstantsMod, {foo} from './constants';

angular.module(..., [myConstantsMod])...
```

It depends on what `foo` import is for, but generally non-default ES6 imports/ exports should be limited to language-specific usage (abstract classes, base objects, etc.) and shouldn't replace Angular modular functionality, which is indispensable due to its testability.